# Error Accessing Kubernetes Dashboard On Bare Metal Kubernetes Cluster Setup

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have deployed Kubernetes dashboard on the bare metal setup using the command:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Then I executed the following command on worker node as mentioned in link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#deploying-the-dashboard-ui

```
kubectl proxy
```

Now I entered the address `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/` on browser window opened on the worker node. I get connection refused message for this address and following error message is displayed on the proxy which I have started on the worker node

```
I0919 15:25:44.138645   23690 logs.go:41] http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
```

What might be the issue in this setting?

Comment: any updates on this one ? did you try metalILB?

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin no i  did not try metalLB, but does it solve the problem?